# Diagonalization of a Matrix. Having Trouble..

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

This is for Continuous-time Markov chains but I'm having trouble with the linear algebra.

**Formal Definitions:**

If Q is diagonalizable, then so is $e^{tQ}$, and the transition function can be expressed in terms of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $Q$. Write $Q=SDS^{-1}$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are the eigenvalues of $Q$, and $S$ is an invertible matrix whose columns are the corresponding eigenvectors. This gives,

$$e^{tQ} = Se^{tD}S^{-1}$$

**The Problem:**

A Markov Chain has generator matrix,

$$Q=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    -1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & -2 & 2 \\
    3 & 0 & -3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Find the transition function by diagonalizing the generator and finding the matrix exponential.

---

My pr0fessor seems to be getting eigenvalues $\lambda = -4, \lambda = -2, \lambda = 0$.

I, on the other hand, seem to be getting $\lambda = -3, \lambda = 0$.

**Edit:** I recalculated but still am getting $\lambda = 0$.

This gets him a completely different set of eigenvectors.. Am I miscalculating something?

**EDIT:**

In the back of the book I have,

$$P(t)=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    -1 & 0 & 1 \\
    -3 & 1 & 1 \\
    3 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    e^{-4t} & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & e^{-2t} & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    -1/4 & 0 & 1/4 \\
    -3/2 & 1 & 1/2 \\
    3/4 & 0 & 1/4 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Where $P(t)$ is the transition function asked for.

Comment: Are you sure you wrote the matrix $Q$ correctly?

Comment: Yes I'm positive. I made sure to double check it several times. Let me include the solution. It's also in the back of my book.

Comment: The reason I ask is, using Wolfram Alpha, the eigenvalues / eigenvectors are http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigensystem+%7B%7B-1,1,0%7D,%7B0,-2,2%7D,%7B3,0,-3%7D%7D

Comment: I added the more formal definitions. I just realized I made a mistake calculating by hand and now I only get one eigenvalue $\lambda = 0$. I am at a complete loss as to what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: There's a typo somewhere.  The first row of $Q$ should be $[-1,0,1]$.

Comment: If the first row is [-1,0,1] do you get the correct eigenvalues? I'll check it again. I have class in a few minutes. I was going to try changing values around. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo.  Reverse engineering the given answer we have:
$$
\begin{align}
Q&=PDP^{-1}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}
    -1 & 0 & 1 \\
    -3 & 1 & 1 \\
    3 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    -4 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & -2 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    -1/4 & 0 & 1/4 \\
    -3/2 & 1 & 1/2 \\
    3/4 & 0 & 1/4 \\
    \end{pmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}
    -1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & -2 & 2 \\
    3 & 0 & -3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

Now knowing that 
$$
Q=\begin{pmatrix}
    -1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & -2 & 2 \\
    3 & 0 & -3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
You can find your characteristic polynomial, e.g. via cofactor expansion down the second column to get $$p(\lambda)=-\lambda(\lambda+2)(\lambda+4)$$ and proceed from there.

Comment: Your methodology was smart. Thank you for your help.